# How to cache url aliases properly in Drupal 7

Tags: caching, path-aliases

I have heard Drupal 7 caches url aliases per page. This is not useful if you are caching pages in Varnish for example. The D6 module [Pathcache](http://drupal.org/project/pathcache) was effectively for this purpose however it does not have a proper D7 port. I'm wondering what others are using for this purpose. How are you caching url_aliases?